# How to add RadioButtonList to certain items in a CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist, radiobuttonlist

I'm not sure what I'm asking is possible but I'm open to any and all suggestions.

I have to pull a list of records from a database and display them as a CheckBoxList. Then, some of these records will have associated "questions" in another table with yes/no answers. I need to display them as RadioButtonLists to the right of the associated CheckBoxList items.

For example:

- _ Group 1
- _ Group 2
- _ Group 3 | Can swallows carry coconuts? () Only African Swallows () No
- _ Group 4

Comment: I don't think the default `CheckBoxList` can do this inherently.  Have you tried using a `Repeater` with a `CheckBox` and `RadioButtonList`, and then display the RBL as needed?

Comment: I would say , yes it can be done. but it depends on how you have build your database. Just out of my head I would use 2 repeaters and 2 tables in your database. 1 table the questions for the check buttons and 1 table with the questions with the radio buttons

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please help us help you a bit and include some additional detail in your question.  Things like: what (if any) code you have tried, what other resources you have consulted, any specific road blocks / error messages you've run into would all be great additions and make your question more answerable.

Comment: Thanks all. I currently have an "Applications" table and "App_Questions" table. An sounds like I should abandon using lists and use CheckBoxes and RadioButtons instead. 

xDaevax - There's no specific code or errors. I figured I'd ferret out whether what I was attempting was possible first. I used The Google and searched SO fairly thoroughly without finding anything that was even close to what I was asking before posting up.

Comment: @DaveBlohm, short answer is using the checkbox list and radio button list out of the box will not work the way you are looking for them to work unless you add some elaborate jquery hacks to pull the html together but then odds are you will have issues with the post back and the server being able to parse the content.

Answer (score 0):

you will likely find it easier to build your own lists using a list view.

1. user control for the check box list
2. user control for the radio buttons
3. have public property for ID that will come from the check box data source then feed that to the list view with the radio buttons in it.

the user control that builds the checkbox list could be any number of data repeaters, i prefer the listview control but to each their own. Then imbed the user control for the radio buttons in the layout of the check box control.

Naturally you dont have to have them as two separate controls but i have found this to be helpful when trying to test and debug nested data repeaters. it also helps separate the jobs of both the list and the radio lists.

will try to add an example to this in a little while but hope this helps for now.